# WooCommerce Admin Create Order & Adding Shipping on Order Pay

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating order in the admin.  I added some functionality to the order pay page which is sent to the customer (form-pay.php).  I added ability to remove items from the order as well as update your billing and shipping info (both for the order and account).  I use ajax and calculate_totals() after an item is removed, which works.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get shipping applied to the order.  I need this to happen when the order is created in the admin and when someone removes an item on the frontend.

I tried just setting the shipping post meta but that isn't working.

```
    function my_order_update_shipping($order_id, $items) { 

        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        $order_subtotal = $order->get_subtotal();

        if($order_subtotal > '17.99'){
            update_post_meta($order_id, '_order_shipping', '0');
        }else{
            update_post_meta($order_id, '_order_shipping', '4');
        }
    }

    add_action('woocommerce_before_save_order_items', 'my_order_update_shipping');
```

How can I achieve this?  Or apply a shipping method in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure this out.  Works good but you need to click the "recalculate" button when adding/removing an item in the admin > create order.  The below code applies 1 of 2 shipping methods based on a static subtotal amount.

```
$delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();

foreach ((array) $delivery_zones as $key => $the_zone) {
    $shipping_methods = $the_zone['shipping_methods'];
}

// Apply Correct Shipping Method

if ($order_subtotal > '17.99') {
    $rate = $shipping_methods[2];
    $item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
    $item->set_props(array('method_id' => $rate->id, 'total' => wc_format_decimal($rate->cost)));
    $order->add_item($item);
} else {
    $rate = $shipping_methods[1];
    $item = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
    $item->set_props(array('method_id' => $rate->id, 'total' => wc_format_decimal($rate->cost)));
    $order->add_item($item);
}

$order->calculate_totals();
$order->save();
```